# Android Studio has lost Run Configurations

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, run-configuration

Android Studio lost all the run-configurations of a project and it is not the first time this happened. This always occurs (as far as I can tell), when switching projects and/or having opened an Android project in IntelliJ IDE.

In an attempt to restore them, I've reverted several missing `.xml` files from the `.idea` directory, including `runConfigurations.xml`, which did not yield the desired result. the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/run_configurations/run_configuration_management.html#persistence) does not really help either.

Q: Where are these run configurations being stored, (in order to keep a backup of them)?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html for relevant documentation. When **Share** check-box is enabled it is stored under `.idea/runConfigurations/` directory.

Comment: @Andrey this works for me, can check them in; never noticed that `Share` checkbox top-right, until now. please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in [Run/Debug Configurations Dialog](http://jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html) documentation when: **Share** check-box is enabled Run/Debug Configuration files are stored under `.idea/runConfigurations/` directory.